# Binding a command in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagridview, command

I am trying to bind a button withing datagrid to a custom command.

But for some reason, the command dont get executed.

This is the XAML:

```
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListView Name="ListView1"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=id,Mode=OneWay}" 
                                 Margin="-6,0,-6,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=name,Mode=OneWay}" 
                                 Margin="-6,0,-6,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Path" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=path,Mode=OneWay}" 
                                 Margin="-6,0,-6,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Update" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button CommandParameter="{Binding id}" Command="{Binding ???????????}" Content="Edit"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What should I write instead of the ?????????? in order to show a message with the ID.

---

Found a solution here:

[WPF DataGrid - Button in a column, getting the row from which it came on the Click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168976/wpf-datagrid-button-in-a-column-getting-the-row-from-which-it-came-on-the-cli)

Comment: What does your viewmodel look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in Cells `DataContext`. Within `DataTemplate` it does not see parent context. Try to add your command to Resources and do something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button CommandParameter="{Binding id}" Command="{StaticResource yourCommand}" Content="Edit"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Let me know if there will be some problems with adding command to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Create a command Inherit from ICommand interface.

```
public class ShowMessageWithIdCommand : ICommand
{
// Implement it members
}
```

in your viewmodel:

```
public ICommand ShowMessageWithIdCommand
{
   get{return new ShowMessageWithIdCommand(...);}
}
```

Then your ????? will be: ShowMessageWithIdCommand

More detail you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx