# Firing a RelayCommand from a button inside a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I have a `DataGrid` showing a list of customers defined in XAML as follows bound to my ViewModel:

```
<DataGrid Name="CustomersDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding showCustomerCommand}" 
                        Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The display of the grid works fine. I want to be able to display the particulars of an individual customer. Previously, I had setup a binding for the selected row, and had a button on the page which was bound to the following command:

```cs
RelayCommand _showCustomerCommand;
public ICommand showCustomerCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_showCustomerCommand == null)
        {
            _showCustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowCustomer());
        }
        return _showCustomerCommand;
    }
}

private void ShowCustomer()
{
    if (Parent != null)
    {
        // Handle Customer Display Here
    }
}
```

This worked fine. But I want to be able to click a button inside the individual row, rather than the single button based on selected row. I know the datacontext is wrong in the above XAML, but I don't know how to correct it, nor how to pass out the specific row from which the button press originated. Any and all suggestions to help me wire up my embedded button are gratefully received!

Comment: Hey, I know I'm grave-digging a bit here, but did you find a solution to this situation? I'm attempting to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 37):

This will help you

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button 
                          Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.showCustomerCommand,       
 RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
  AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 8):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168976/wpf-datagrid-button-in-a-column-getting-the-row-from-which-it-came-on-the-cli) question/answer looks similar to what you're looking for.

You can bind the ID of the row to the command parameter

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Command="{Binding showCustomerCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ID}">View Details</Button>
```

Comment: It is similar, but it relates to conventional code behind, not the MVVM pattern I am trying to use. Thank you though!

Comment: Please read the answers carefully. Also, in my answer I gave you the MVVM way. Your binding stays the same, but now there is a parameter you can use in your command.

Comment: I understand; thank you. I was however, as per my question title looking for guidance as to how I can use it with a relaycommand. In short, I was hoping for a little more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Resharper/Intellisense inference is incorrect inside of `DataGridTemplate`.

This can cause confusion, In order to correct that, the DataTemplate should have an explicit DataType referencing the type that the row is being bound to.

There are 2 ways I found of solving your question, Using a Relative Binding for the Command , so that it binds using the Context of the DataGrid, not the current row, Or creating an x:Name attribute on an element that has the context you wish to bind to.

It's my belief that the relative binding is cleaner if you are trying to access an ancestor, but if you need to bind to something elsewhere in the tree, then maybe ElementName will allow that.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBindings.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBindings"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:WindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GroupBox x:Name="Test"  Header="Grid" Grid.Column="0"> <!-- #2 Add a name to the element you need to bind to. -->
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RowList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="local:RowViewModel"><!-- Needed for correct inference in XAML editor -->
                                <!-- #1 Cleaner solution as it doesn't depend on names -->
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=RowCount}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NineCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                <!-- #2 Naming the element explicitly probably allows you to jump elsewhere in the tree -->
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=RowCount}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NineCommand, ElementName=Test}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=SelectedRow.RowCount}" Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=RowList/RowCount}"></Label>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

namespace TestBindings
{
    public class RowViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        private static int _max = 0;
        private int _rowCount;

        public int RowCount
        {
            get { return _rowCount; }
            set
            {
                if (_rowCount == value) return;
                _rowCount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RowCount));
            }
        }

        public RowViewModel()
        {
            _rowCount = _max++;
        }
    }

    public class TypedCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<T> _execute;

        public TypedCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
        {
            this._canExecute = canExecute;
            this._execute = execute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T) parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute?.Invoke((T) parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }

    public class WindowViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RowViewModel> RowList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<RowViewModel>();

        private RowViewModel _selectedRow;

        public RowViewModel SelectedRow
        {
            get { return _selectedRow; }
            private set
            {
                if (_selectedRow == value) return;
                _selectedRow = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRow));
            }
        }

        private static readonly Action<RowViewModel> DeleteAction = new Action<RowViewModel>(row => row.RowCount=99);

        public ICommand NineCommand { get; } = new TypedCommand<RowViewModel>(DeleteAction);

        public WindowViewModel()
        {
            //0
            RowList.Add(new RowViewModel());
            //1
            RowList.Add(new RowViewModel());
            //2
            RowList.Add(new RowViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```