# Adding the word "delete" in a cell of 5th Column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

My question is how to add the word "delete" in a cell of the 5th Column of a DataGridView ?

I am implementing a function of delete, to delete a row when a user clicks anywhere in the 5th column in a DataGridView.

I have no problem handling a CellClick event. But the problem for me is how to add the word "Delete" to each cell of the 5th Column?

Comment: Why not have buttons in the column? Check is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168976/wpf-datagrid-button-in-a-column-getting-the-row-from-which-it-came-on-the-cli) is any help

Answer (score 0):

In code you can use the following statement, which assumes Column(5) is a Button:

```
CType(YourDataGridView.Columns(5), DataGridViewButtonColumn).UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
```

You can also set this property using the Columns property (Appearance section) of the DataGridView control.

Comment: under the appearance, i just can see the "DefaultCellStyle" and "Header Text" and "Tooltip Text" and "Visible",
and the "Header Text" is not i am looking for.

Comment: You must use a DaataGFridViewButton control for this top work. You can then also replace the "Delete" text with an image.

Comment: Sorry, where you get the DaataGFridViewButton control from ?

Comment: In the Design section, click on "ControlType" - a combo-box with available controls is listed.

Comment: I know you are new to S.O., but if your questions is correctly answer, it is customary to accept (or up-vote) the answer.