# Bind a Button to an object in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am building a WPF app where it includes an action of adding an item to a shopping cart. A `DataGrid` defined as follows is bind to a collection of `Product`s, and a `Button` is present for each row. Now, when a `Button` is clicked, how do I know *which* `Product` object it is for?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding }" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" TextBlock.FontSize="20" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="2*" SortMemberPath="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" SortMemberPath="{Binding Name}"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Add To Cart" Width="2*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Click To Add"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You want to do in MVVM way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168976/wpf-datagrid-button-in-a-column-getting-the-row-from-which-it-came-on-the-cli

Comment: @paul, thanks. just saw that post too.

Comment: @Sajeetharan paul's link gives me a good solution. just curious, what's the MVVM way like?

Comment: I think you can override Product class and have there a method, which will handle buttonClick. So when you will create a command for datagridrowButtonClick it will be binded to your method in ProductClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind Product to `Tag` Property of `Button` Like this :

```
<Button Content="Click To Add" Tag="{Binding}"/>
```

You will get original entity by :

```
Product product = button.Tag as Product
```