# Telerik RadGridView selected item binding not working when clicking on button in datagrid properly

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

Hi I have a telerik RadGridView bound up to an observable collection via MVVM and the `SelectedItem` property of the grid is also bound to a property from within the model as well. There is then a button column that is bound to open the selected item to see more details of the selected item. The code for this is below.

```
           <telerik:RadGridView Name="RadGridView"
                         Height="900"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         CanUserSortColumns="True"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Items}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Width="990">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>


                <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Open Item" >
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Open"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenItemBySelectedItemCommand,
                                RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}">
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn>


                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding DateScanned}" Header="Date Scanned"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Amount}" Header="Amount"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsRefund}" Header="Is Refund"  />

            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Now this code works fine whenever I click into the row then click the button, however if I just click the button of the row without clicking into the row first the `SelectedItem` property is not set and so the command does not function as expected.

I thought when clicking the button of a row it would auto select that row but apparently not. Does anyone know how I can get it to set the `SelectedItem` property whenever I only click on the button within a specific row without having to click on the row before clicking the button?

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168976/wpf-datagrid-button-in-a-column-getting-the-row-from-which-it-came-on-the-cli

Comment: The MVVM solution in that link seems to break the binding of my command but ill have a play about with it and see if I can get that sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a reference to the underlying data object as a command parameter to the command:

```
<Button Content="Open"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenItemBySelectedItemCommand, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
</Button>
```

For the row to actually become selected when you click on the `Button`, you will have to write some code that actually selects it. You could do this by handling the `Button`'s `Click` event like this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    RadGridView.SelectedItem = button.DataContext;
}
```

---

```
<Button Content="Open"
        Click="Button_Click_1"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenItemBySelectedItemCommand,
        RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}">
</Button>
```

This does *not* break the MVVM pattern since selecting a row in the view is pure view functionality.